# TryParse Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tryparse

I have question on my code below. I am trying to use an `int.TryParse` method to check for a user's input (if user puts "abc" on the TextBox, it should display an error telling the user, it is the wrong input, and that they should input a whole number.). I was wondering why my code doesn't want to work. Here is what I have:

```
private void CalcStayChargesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Get the user input.
     NumberOfDays = int.Parse(DaysInHospitalChargesTextBox.Text);
     if (int.TryParse(DaysInHospitalChargesTextBox.Text, out NumberOfDays))
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number.");
     }
}
```

There are no errors when in code view, but when I run the application to test it, it goes back to the 4th line and highlights it, but I couldn't figure it out. Keep in mind the NumberOfDays integer is set below the beginning of the form already so that I could use it universally throughout the application. Will someone please give me any hints on how to make it work? I might have overlooked something. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (int.TryParse(DaysInHospitalChargesTextBox.Text, out NumberOfDays))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number.");
        }
```

by doing this if the parsing is successful then this message is displayed you should instead do this

```
if (!int.TryParse(DaysInHospitalChargesTextBox.Text, out NumberOfDays))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number.");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`int.TryParse` returns false, when parsing wasn't possible, so you have to put `!` into your condition:

```
private void CalcStayChargesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the user input.
    if (!int.TryParse(DaysInHospitalChargesTextBox.Text, out NumberOfDays))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number.");
    }
}
```

Why using `int.Parse` and then `int.TryParse`? Use one of them, not both.

You also has to have a variable called `NumberOfDays` which has to be of `int` type. If there is no such a variable in class, add one before `if` statement:

```
int NumberOfDays;
if(!int.TryParse(...))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
private void CalcStayChargesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the user input.
    int NumberOfDays;
    if (!int.TryParse(DaysInHospitalChargesTextBox.Text, out NumberOfDays))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number.");
    }
}
```

Your first call to int.Parse will throw an Exception if it's not a parse-able number -- that's what TryParse is for, it just returns false if it can't parse the number.  Also, your logic was displaying the message when it is a valid number, so you need the `!` in there to make the statement resolve to true if the number can't be parsed.

Comment: Oh, okay. I totally overlooked that I tried to Parse twice. Sorry about this everyone. This was too simple. Thank you all who helped me. This should be enough for me to complete my application, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

int.TryParse(Something, out value) try to parse the value of "Something" and set the value to out (if this was ok).
int.TryParse returns true if this was ok (and false for not ok.)

So for your example what you should do is :

```
private void CalcStayChargesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int NumberOfDays; //Create the variable
     //try to parse DaysInHosputalChargesTextBox.Text
     if (!(int.TryParse(DaysInHospitalChargesTextBox.Text, out NumberOfDays))) 
     {
         // "!" means the parsing was not ok. So the user should reenter the number     
         MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number.");
     }
     else
     {
         //some code to do if the parsing was successful. 
     }
}
```

See [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

See how is [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) used

```
private void CalcStayChargesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int NumberOfDays;
    if (!int.TryParse(DaysInHospitalChargesTextBox.Text, out NumberOfDays))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a whole number.");
    }
}
```